# Aligning a marginpar with a line box inside a list

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

I'd like to write a LaTeX environment that automatically places a `\marginpar` next to the first line of text within.  However, that first line of text might not be part of an ordinary paragraph; it can be something like a list item.

In order for the `\marginpar` to align with the first line of an *ordinary* paragraph, I have to use `\leavevmode` to ensure that the `\marginpar` is placed in the same line box as the text that follows it; otherwise it's positioned too high.  But if what follows is a list, this just creates a *blank* line for the `\marginpar` to align with, and the list goes below it.

This example illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{reversemarginpar}

\newenvironment{category}{
  \leavevmode\marginpar{\raggedleft Label}
}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{category}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  \end{category}

  \begin{category}
    % Label is aligned with this line.
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
      \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{category}
\end{document}
```

The second category's label is positioned next to the blank line where the commented-out text would appear if it were uncommented.  I'd like it to appear next to the line that says "Item 1" instead.

I believe this happens because the `itemize` list begins with something (probably a `\par`) that terminates the current line box and begins a new one.  If I could tell TeX to inject the `\marginpar` into the beginning of the next line box it creates, rather than creating one explicitly with `\leavevmode`, I think that would resolve the problem.  But I don't know how to do that.

Is there a way to make this work?

**Update:**  After further consideration, this doesn't necessarily need to be a `\begin{category}` environment.  I'm actually using this in a custom document class that consists entirely of a sequence of categories, so it may make more sense to just define a `\category` command that's used like the `\chapter` command in other classes.  The desired output is the same, though.

**Update 2:**  Can I create something analogous to `\llap` in vertical mode?  I tried `\vbox to 0pt{\vss X}\nointerlineskip` hoping that the X would overlap with the line of text that follows, but it doesn't.  If I can create a line box that overlaps the material below it, I can use that to position the `\marginpar` so it aligns with the "real" line box that's created later.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the standard `\marginpar` command, you could use `\marginnote` from the [marginnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package, and change the nesting order of your environment and the `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\geometry{reversemarginpar}

\newenvironment{category}{
  \marginnote{\raggedleft Label}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{category}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{category}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \begin{category} Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \end{category}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at the marginnote package, but I don't think the reversed nesting order you suggested will work well for me:  I'd like to be able to put multiple paragraphs (and/or lists, etc.) within a single category.